# Resume multithreaded application in PyCharm debug

Tags: multithreading, debugging, pycharm, pdb

Consider the following situation:

- We have a multithreaded app
- We're paused at one thread at the breakpoint
- we set a breakpoint in another line of code
- a new threads hits that breakpoint
- so we have 2 threads paused at the same time
- we want to resume the 2nd thread but still having the 1st one paused
- if we select that thread and click resume -> both threads would resume

is there a way to resume only 1 thread? [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owKaOCSB6RE)